# Continuation Token for CosmosDB Graph queries

Tags: linq, pagination, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I have successfully implemented a Continuation Query Token using the DocumentDB API for a collection using [this example](http://hershbhasin.com/2017/09/a-pagination-strategy-for-a-cosmosdb-api/).

Now I need to switch to a Graph API because it's a much better fit for the social networking app I am building. How can I execute paginated queries with the continuation token when using a Graph DB API. I was unable to find any examples that accomplish the same.

Comment: Hello,have you tried with the range step? http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#range-step

Comment: I am a little confused. One of the pre-alpha releases makes it look like Microsoft is fully embrancing Gremlin and ditching Microsoft.Azure.Graphs library. I guess we'll have to wait and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination with continuation tokens is currently not supported in CosmosDB Graph. However it does support streaming batches of results to the client, so depending on your use case this may be enough. Note that some gremlin driver clients do not support yielding partial results to the caller.

Currently there isn't a way to control the batch size that the server sends, and it is configured to buffer if accumulated result is < 4Kb.

Comment: I've found the static Run method in Azure functions to be really annoying. Hopefully Microsoft will rethink it's azure functions architecture to include a DI engine that I can plug all my config into. Also, making the functions reactive out of the box will help me build reactive streaming architectures around functions.